# React: rendering components in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, render

All the docs for `map` use braces but the code below and most examples I see when dealing with React use parenthesis. I'm trying to figure out exactly what the difference is and what the code is doing.

When using braces, nothing renders unless I specifically add `return`. So my take is that the parenthesis act as some sort of inline function that automatically returns or React converts the result and inlines it into the JSX?

```
// Renders fine
render()
{
   return (
      <div className="item-list">
         {
            this.props.items.map(
               ( _item, _index ) => (
               <ItemComponent
                  key={ _index }
                  name={ _item.name }
                  description={ _item.description }
               />
            ) )
         }
      </div>
   );
}

// Nothing
render()
{
   return (
      <div className="item-list">
         {
            this.props.items.map(
               ( _item, _index ) => 
               {
                  <ItemComponent
                     key={ _index }
                     name={ _item.name }
                     description={ _item.description }
                  />
               } )
         }
      </div>
   );
}

// Renders fine
render()
{
   return (
      <div className="item-list">
         {
            this.props.items.map(
               ( _item, _index ) => 
               {
                  return <ItemComponent
                     key={ _index }
                     name={ _item.name }
                     description={ _item.description }
                  />
               } )
         }
      </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: You are talking about function shorthand called arrow functions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with React, It is all about javascript

Curly braces saying it is a function body so we need to manually use `return` keyword

```
 this.props.items.map(
               ( _item, _index ) => 
               { // Note: represent function body, normal javascript function
                  <ItemComponent
                     key={ _index }
                     name={ _item.name }
                     description={ _item.description }
                  />
               } )
```

According to `arrow functions`, has implicit return behavior hence so need to mention explicitly if single line expression.

```
render()
{
   return (
      <div className="item-list">
         {
            this.props.items.map(
               ( _item, _index ) => ( // Note: single line expression, so impilicit;y return our ItemComponent
               <ItemComponent
                  key={ _index }
                  name={ _item.name }
                  description={ _item.description }
               />
            ) )
         }
      </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: You forgot it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

So parenthesis in an arrow function returns a single value, the curly braces are used when executing multiple lines of code and not just a simple return, so a manual return statement is required just because javascript can't know what among those lines to return.

```
materials.map(material => ({key:material.name}));
```

return an object

```
materials.map(material => {
   let newMat = material.name+'_new'; 
   return newMat;
});
```

we need to return since we are doing 1 or many lines of manipulation and trying to return end result